# Need help refactoring my vuejs code. Error v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Someone recommended that I should use bootstrap-vue because I am using bootstrap 4 and vue together; I believe I installed bootstrap-vue for laravel correctly.

My goal:
I am using VueJS 2.6.11 and bootstrap 4 to create two dynamic sections(Category and Product) that contain divs and input fields. The product section is nested within the category section. When someone clicks the New Category button another category should get generated. The same behavior should also happen when someone clicks the New Product button, another Product section should get generated, but only inside the current category section.

I am receiving the following error when I click on the New Product button:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined"

found in

---> <CreateProductAndCategory> at resources/js/components/admin/CreateProductAndCategory.vue
       <Dashboard> at resources/js/views/admin/DashBoard.vue
         <App> at resources/js/components/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Original code:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: ".container",

  data: {
    categories: [{
      name: "",
      products: [{
        name: ""
      }]
    }]
  },

  methods: {
    addNewCategoryForm() {
      this.categories.push({
        name: "",
        products: []
      });
    },

    deleteCategoryForm(index) {
      this.categories.splice(index, 1);
    },

    addNewProductForm(index) {
      this.categories[index].products.push({
        name: ""
      });
    },

    deleteProductForm(categoryIndex, index) {
      this.categories[categoryIndex].products.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Vue -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<title>Create Categories and Products</title>
<div class="container">
  <!-- New Category -->
  <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewCategoryForm">
        New Category
      </button>

  <div class="card mb-3" v-for="(category, catIndex) in categories">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="float-right" style="cursor:pointer" @click="deleteCategoryForm">
            X
          </span>

      <h4 class="card-title">Add Category</h4>

      <div class="category-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Category Name" v-model="category.name">
      </div>

      <!-- New Product -->
      <button class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5" @click="addNewProductForm(catIndex)">
            New Product
          </button>

      <div class="card mb-3" v-for="(product, index) in category.products">
        <div class="card-body">
          <span class="float-right" style="cursor:pointer" @click="deleteProductForm(catIndex, index)">
                X
              </span>

          <h4 class="card-title">Add Product</h4>

          <div class="product-form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Product Name" v-model="product.name">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Refactored code (The code that I am receiving the errors for):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- New Category -->
        <b-button variant="success" class="mt-1 mb-2"
                @click="addNewCategoryForm">
            New Category
        </b-button>

        <b-card class="mb-3" v-for="(category, catIndex) in categories">
            <span class="float-right"
                style="cursor:pointer"
                @click="deleteCategoryForm">
                X
            </span>

            <h4 class="card-title">Add Category</h4>

            <div class="category-form">
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control mb-2"
                    placeholder="Category Name"
                    v-model="category.name">
            </div>

            <!-- New Product -->
            <b-button variant="success" class="mt-2 mb-2"
                    @click="addNewProductForm">
                New Product
            </b-button>

            <b-card class="mb-3" v-for="(product, index) in category.products">
                <span class="float-right" 
                    style="cursor:pointer"
                    @click="deleteProductForm">
                    X
                </span>

                <h4 class="card-title">Add Product</h4>

                <div class="product-form">
                    <input 
                    type="text" 
                    class="form-control mb-2" 
                    placeholder="Product Name"
                    v-model="product.name">
                </div>
            </b-card>

        </b-card>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "create-product-and-category",

    data: () => {
        return {
            categories: [{
                name: "",
                products: [{
                    name: ""
                }]
            }]
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addNewCategoryForm() {
            this.categories.push({
                name: "",
                products: []
            });
        },

        deleteCategoryForm(index) {
            this.categories.splice(index, 1);
        },

        addNewProductForm(index) {
            this.categories[index].products.push({
                name: ""
            });
        },

        deleteProductForm(categoryIndex, index) {
            this.categories[categoryIndex].products.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue.  I need to pay closer attention while copying and pasting.

This is the correct code snippet:

```
 <!-- New Product -->
            <b-button variant="success" class="mt-2 mb-2"
                    @click="addNewProductForm(catIndex)">
                New Product
            </b-button>

            <b-card class="mb-3" v-for="(product, index) in category.products">
                <span class="float-right" 
                    style="cursor:pointer"
                    @click="deleteProductForm(catIndex, index)">
                    X
                </span>
```